# Using composer command

Tags: php, composer-php

I have some problems.

```
C:/apps>composer require musonza/chat
```

> Using version ^3.7 for musonza/chat
>   Root package 'musonza/chat' cannot require itself in its composer.json

I can't find the solution from anywhere. Do you know the solution?

Comment: And what's your project name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to require `musonza/chat` in the clone of that package or your project name has the same name as the package that you want to install/require.

You should install `musonza/chat` on the laravel project because it's a package for laravel.

Try step below to create a laravel project :

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel chat
```

go to chat folder then install the package:

```
composer require musonza/chat
```

then publish the assets of that package:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

See `musonza_chat.php` for configuration

then run the migrations:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Note: The requirement of laravel 6 is PHP 7.2 or above, so please install it

Answer (score 0):

If you clone from git or downloaded run `composer install` instead of `composer require musonza/chat`